# Python 2.7 shortcut commands doesn't work with russian keyboard layout

Tags: python-2.7, keyboard-shortcuts, python-idle

I use Python 2.7.8 IDLE for script writing.

When keyboard layout is english - shortcut commands (Ctrl+c, Ctrl+z, etc.) works well. But when I switched to russian keyboard layout these shortcuts commands does nothing.

**How to fix that?**

EDIT 1:
OS Windows 7, Tk ver: 8.5.15

[image]

Comment: What OS, what version of tcl/tk, which is listed in Help - About IDLE.  You should have a recent 8.5 or 8.6 version for non-ascii keyboards.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy See new edit.

Comment: You have the tk patch I am thinking of.  The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116195/why-some-characters-can-not-be-typed-in-pythons-idle *might* shed some light on this issue.  Or perhaps a different Russian keyboard program might work better.  I have no experience with non-english keyboards myself.